# RXJS and Angular - Should I be using ReplaySubject and Observable?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I've built a modal dialog that allows a developer to specify their own content in the body. It has two buttons at the bottom - **Yes** or **Cancel**.

The developer implementing their own modal, can choose to subscribe/not to subscribe to the Yes or Cancel buttons.

There are a lot of options I can choose from for signalling from the Modal back to the page that Yes or Cancel have been clicked. I can use **BehaviourSubject**, **ReplaySubject**, **Observable**, **EventEmitter**.

I want the modal to close itself when Yes or Cancel is clicked and proceed to tell the calling page that something has occurred.

I have added a **.do()** to close the modal before the subscriber gets notified. I have also added a default subscription in the **ngAfterViewInit()** incase no one handles say the Cancel event.

**Question: Should I be ReplaySubject and Observable in this manner or is there a better way to handle this?**

**modal.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-modal',
  templateUrl: './modal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./modal.component.css']
})
export class ModalComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  // Outputs
  @Output() onYesClicked: Observable<void>;
  @Output() onNoClicked: Observable<void>;
  @Output() onCancelClicked: Observable<void>;

  private yesReplaySubject: ReplaySubject<void> = new ReplaySubject<void>();
  private noReplaySubject: ReplaySubject<void> = new ReplaySubject<void>();
  private cancelReplaySubject: ReplaySubject<void> = new ReplaySubject<void>();

  constructor() {
    this.configuration = new DefaultModalConfigurationBuilder().build();
    // Do a follow up action of hiding the modal when a replay subject is triggered
    this.onYesClicked =     this.yesReplaySubject.do(x => this.hide());
    this.onNoClicked =      this.noReplaySubject.do(x => this.hide());
    this.onCancelClicked =  this.cancelReplaySubject.do(x => this.hide());
  }

 public ngAfterViewInit() {
    // Some subscription set up incase no one handles the cancel click etc...
    this.onYesClicked.subscribe();
    this.onNoClicked.subscribe();
    this.onCancelClicked.subscribe();
  }

  private yesClicked = (): void => this.yesReplaySubject.next(null);
  private noClicked = (): void => this.noReplaySubject.next(null);
  private cancelClicked = (): void => this.cancelReplaySubject.next(null);
}
```

**modal.html**

```
<ng-content></ng-content>
<div class="pull-right">
  <button class="btn btn-primary"
          [disabled]="!form.valid"
          *ngIf="configuration.modalButtonConfiguration.yesButtonEnabled"
          (click)="yesClicked()">
    {{configuration.modalButtonConfiguration.yesButtonText}}
  </button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary"
          *ngIf="configuration.modalButtonConfiguration.cancelButtonEnabled"
          (click)="cancelClicked()">
    {{configuration.modalButtonConfiguration.cancelButtonText}}
  </button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary"
          *ngIf="configuration.modalButtonConfiguration.noButtonEnabled"
          (click)="noClicked()">
    {{configuration.modalButtonConfiguration.noButtonText}}
  </button>
</div>
```

**app.html**

```
<app-modal title="Modal Demo (onYesClicked)="handleYesClicked()">
  <form novalidate>
    <p>My modal content</p>
  </form>
</app-modal>
```

**app.ts**

```
...
private onYesClicked(): void {
// Do something here
}
...
```